# Is there a way to insert additional icons into an iOS IPA file without rebuilding in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios7, icons, ipa

I have an iOS 5 app that needs some additional icon files for iOS7 but I would like to avoid having to recompile it just to add them. Is there any way to "inject" these missing icon file pngs into the compiled app/plist or is there no way to do this outside rebuilding with Xcode? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. 
The icons will be compiled with the code.
Also you can not change the path to the icon, course its also compiled.